# How to have a navbar similar to the one on Twitter Bootstrap's website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can we create a navbar similar to the one on Twitter Boostrap's website? The navbar is black, and more importantly is centered in the middle of the page. The alignment of the links seem to be too high too.

The navbar created using the code below is aligned to the left. How do you get it to be centered with a max width like on Twitter Bootstrap's website.

**Target navbar**

[image]

**Attempt**

[image]

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scaffolding</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to know how a specific site accomplished something. Try having a look at their code. Right click and hit view page source.

Comment: Use the sauce, Luke... https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap , more specifically http://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less

Comment: Can you create on jsffidle or cssdesk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one nice technique i like for aligning the links always to the center is to use line-height:

```
.navbar-inner { height: 60px; }
.nav { line-height: 60px; }
```

make it the same as the height of the container div, whether this is placed on .navbar-inner or .nav is your call. but it will make the text of the links always vertically aligned in the middle.

Using the bootstrap framework, .navbar-inner should have the same css applied to it as .container or .container-fluid (depending on if you are using the fluid layout or not). For non-fluid layouts this means the following rules:

```
.navbar-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1140px; /* or whatever width you choose for your .container */
}
```

fluid layouts this means:
    .navbar-inner {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to put everything inside the `navbar-inner` inside a `<div class="container">`.